# is it possible to run an Rmd code chunk inside another code chunk?

Tags: r, r-markdown, code-reuse

I want to rerun a code chunk at the beginning of another code chunk in order to avoid repeating them. Is there a way to do this using the code chunk label?

Answer (score 1):

Following the [R Markdown Cookbook](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/reuse-chunks.html#reuse-chunks) you could include a code chunk in another code chunk using `<<LABEL-OF-CODE-CHUNK-TO-BE-INCLUDED>>`:

````
---
title: "Reuse of code chunks"
output: html_document
date: "2022-10-19"
---

This is chunk a:
```{r chunk-a}
1 + 1
```

This is chunk b which includes chunk a:
```{r chunk-b}
<<chunk-a>>
2 + 2
```
````

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much stefan.
But this code results in the following error:
Error: unexpected input in "<<"

after further googling this error I guess this is because Rsutio does not evaluate <<>> symbols and you only can kint the rmd file including these symbols. Am I right?

Comment: Hm. Interesting. I just checked and the code works fine for me. Have you knitted the code? Or have you just run the code? The last will not work and gives me the  error you mentioned.

Comment: Yes, it works when I knit the code. But I thought there might be a way to reuse the previous chunks on the go, without knitting the notebook.